# Java map implementation that preserves insertion order AND stores keys by reference?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have seen questions on the two characteristics separately, but not at the same time, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

Basically, I came across a problem where a possible solution is a `Map` data structure that let you traverse the map in the order in which entries were inserted *and* stores keys by reference as opposed to using `equals()`.

I have tested some implementations for this, but none seem to posses both characteristics. `LinkedHashMap` and `TreeMap` preserves order (traversed using `map.entrySet()`), but they utilise `hashCode()` or `equals()`. On the other hand, we have `IdentityHashMap` which is the only one (I think) that stores objects by reference, but unfortunately doesn't preserve order.

So my question is: is there a `Map` implementation that fits both criteria? If not, what would be a way to create a `Map` with such behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "stores keys by reference"? All map implementations retain references to inserted keys.

Comment: What do you mean by a "reference"?  Java syntax doesn't have references.  But all objects are accessed by reference by the JVM, so when you pass an object around, the JVM is actually using a reference to that object.  Primitives are passed by value.

Comment: @jacobm I read somewhere that most map implementations stores keys by using `equals()`. In other words, there can never be two entries that are equal to each other in such implemented map. Storing by reference means that regardless of `equals()` or `hackCode()` equality, two such objects can exists as different keys in the map. E.g. `one = new Integer(1)` and `one2 = new Integer(1)` would overwrite each other if put in a map, because they are equal. However, storing by reference means that they are two separate keys because they don't point to the same object.

Comment: @teppic yes! ty so much